# Tensorflow no longer knows placeholder or only works with the cpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Hello I have a problem with my tensorflow script. The script worked without problems, the past few years.
Now I get the error after reinstalling tensorflow:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

I tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

With

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior ()
```

to replace, which in turn brings the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'truncated_normal'
```

so I undid it and uninstalled tensorflow and:

```
pip3.6.exe install tensorflow == 1.9
```

Installed.
now the script runs through, but only on the CPU.
therefore:

```
pip3.6.exe install tensorflow-gpu
```

this follows to the output:

```
ERROR: tensorflow 1.9.0 has requirement tensorboard <1.10.0,> = 1.9.0, but you'll have tensorboard 2.1.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorboard 2.1.0 has requirement setuptools> = 41.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 39.1.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: tensorboard, tensorflow-gpu
  Attempting uninstall: tensorboard
    Found existing installation: tensorboard 1.9.0
    Uninstalling tensorboard-1.9.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorboard-1.9.0
Successfully installed tensorboard-2.1.0 tensorflow-gpu-2.1.0
```

and again about the mistake:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder'
```

out of that i got out

```
tf.placeholder()

tf.truncated_normal()
```

that done

```
tf.compat.v1.placeholder()

tf.random.truncated_normal()
```

but this leads to:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\check_ops.py", line 2101, in assert_scalar
    % (message or '', tensor.name, shape))
ValueError: Expected scalar shape for keepProb:0, saw shape: <unknown>.
```

What should I do?
with what do I have to replace placeholder? or which configuration of versions do I have to install?
Why are there no more placeholders?

Help Please

Comment: you've installed `tensorflow-gpu v2.1.0` try to install the `v1.9` as for `tensorflow`

Comment: the script runs through, but still seems to only use the CPU

Answer (score 0):

They deprecated the placeholder concept because it was too complicated to understand, especially for beginners. They replaced it with `tf.variable`. So if you had something like this before:
`x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 227, 227, 3])`

you have to change it to this:

`x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(1, 227, 227, 3)), name='x', dtype=tf.float32)`

For the `truncated_normal` you have to change:

`initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)`

to:

`initial = tf.random.truncated_normal(
    shape, mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32, seed=None, name=None
)`

after upgrading to tensorflow 2.0.

Comment: ok and what is with:  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)

Answer (score 0):

This is the version compatibility issues. Now the version of tensorflow is 2.1.0 which has many differences from version 1.x. First you’d better using the command below to convert your TensorFlow python files from version 1.x to version 2.x.

`tf_upgrade_v2 --infile file_v1.py --outfile file_v2.py`

You may encounter other problems later, but please do the above work first. Other issues later may be easier to solve.